# Dataweave: How to split a string by a max length without breaking any word

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft

I have a string like this:

> "This is a native string for splitting test"

and I am having a Dataweave fun to split string as belows:

```
fun divideBy(str: String, size: Number): Array<String> = flatten(str scan ".{1,$(size)}") 
---
(payload.message divideBy 15) map (trim($))
```

The output now is:

> [
> "This is a nativ",
> "e string for sp",
> "litting test"
> ]

However, I want to split this string by Maximum Length 15 and the splitting must be done only by the Nearest Spaces in it..(before at index 15 and not in the middle of a word)
For example:

> [
> "This is a",
> "native string",
> "for splitting",
> "test"
> ]

How can I get the expected result?

Comment: The output that you shared as the output of your dataweave. does not match the actual output. Probably you meant to do `divideBy 15` instead of `divideBy 36`.  in your dataweave?

Comment: Thanks guy, this is just a typo mistake. I have edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a non capturing group to your regex that matches either a trailing space or the end character ($), i.e. `(?:\s|$)` so your expression will become something like this

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
var testString = "This is a native string for splitting test"
fun divideBy(str: String, size: Number): Array<String> = 
    str scan ".{1,$(size)}(?:\s|\$)"
        map trim($[0])

---
testString divideBy 15
```